# Bundle several images together for HTTP?

Tags: javascript, http, web

I have a page with several hundreds of small images that need to be loaded when the page is visited. The total amount of data is 11 MB but it still takes upwards of 11 seconds to load the entire page.
Looking at the chrome network profiler, it pretty evident that the majority of time is wasted waiting for connections. A typical image has:
- 0.13 ms    - Request sent
- 240.01 ms  - Waiting (TTFB)
- 1.13 ms    - Content Download
This, with Chrome's policy of only 6 TCP connections in parallal mean that many images wait 10 seconds to be downloaded.

So clearly the problem is in the server that takes a long time to answer each request but unfortunately that's the only piece that I can't control. That server is not going to change and I can't do any caching of technology change.

Is there a way to pack all the images into a single download and then unpack in in JS in the browser? I know about the dataurl method but I was hoping for a way that would avoid the base64 bloat

EDIT:
Note that the images are part of a big SVG in the page so will the sprites solution work in an SVG?

Comment: Sprites: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Images/Implementing_image_sprites_in_CSS

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I bundle images into one file for a web page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11876985/can-i-bundle-images-into-one-file-for-a-web-page)

Comment: Use HTTP/2 to pipeline it all together…

Comment: @deceze how do I specify HTTP/2 usage from a webpage? I have no control of the server serving it

Comment: Then you're a bit out of luck. Of course the server will need to support it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [CSS sprite sheets](https://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/).

Live example: [bkmks.com](https://www.bkmks.com) uses this trick to speed up loading lots favicons with a [sprite sheet like this](https://www.bkmks.com/bk/favSprite/11003722648323748486082417842223813405.png).

---

**update:** The workflow and syntax are slightly different, but SVG sprites are also possible:

- [A Guide to Create and Use SVG Sprites](https://w3bits.com/svg-sprites/)
- [How to Create and Manage SVG Sprites](https://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2017/05/how-to-create-and-manage-svg-sprites/)

Since you have raster images inside an SVG, you may also have to do the sprite trick *inside* the SVG. The [SVG `image` syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/SVG_Image_Tag) seems to support it.

If the actual images are just pure raster images (the SVG is just a "container"), I would try to remove the SVG layer. This will involve replacing all the references in the HTML to the SVG with references to the CSS sprite sheet.

Comment: Unexpected problem: the images are actually in a big SVG that is part of the page HTML. From a quick test it seems that svg element don't respond to CSS background property.
Any ideas?

Comment: @shoosh: Updated answer to account for SVG images

Comment: Sorry, I still can't figure it out.. I have raster images inside an SVG that has other vector images as well. I want all the raster images to be in the same sprites image. I can use x="" and y="" to specify an offset in the big image but the big image still scales according to the small image width="" and height=""

Comment: Ah, I was missing preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin slice"